# Compare datetime field with date using jpa query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have `start_date` as *datetime* field in date base which stores both date and time. I want to check the current date (only date not time) is same as `start_date`.

I am using JPA for data base operation. For example, if the start_date in DB is `2016-03-19 03:33:45`, i want to check the start_date (2016-03-19) is equal to current date (2016-03-19) excluding time data.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use `q.setParameter("yourdatetimefieldname", c, TemporalType.DATE)`

Comment: but the  start_date is  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP).In this case did the above solution work?

Comment: My mistake. I don't think there is JPA date related function that will help here. One option I see is using a query `where start_date > :targetDate and createdOn < :targetDateNextDay` with `setParameter("targetDate", targetDate, TemporalType.DATE)` and `setParameter("targetDateNextDay", targetDateNextDay, TemporalType.DATE)`

Comment: Answered that question here last week. Please do a search.